# Multiple commands in one line fails

Tags: linux

Multiple commands in one line fails on Linux. This is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>d.txt && cp ../file1.txt file1.txt
```

The copy command is not getting executed as if its not there at all. No errors are given, just does not works. It gets executed if I do not redirect the output of first command to a file.

So I tried to run the command on DOS to see if that throws some error, and it gave this error:

> Unexpected '&&' symbol.

There also the command works if I do not redirect output of first command into a file.

I want the solution for Linux. DOS was just an attempt to find out some error message.

Comment: DOS version was this: c:\ffmpeg.exe -i video.mp4 2>d.txt && copy ..\file1.txt file1.txt

Comment: Break the line up and check the result of the command after the first call. (hint.. $? in bash.. ERRORLEVEL in cmd).  You probably have SOMETHING in d.txt  but an app doesn't need to output to STDERR to return a non 0 code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing any error message, because STDERR is redirected to the file d.txt
`cp` is not executing because the ffmpeg command fails.

`command && echo "command gave a return code of 0" || echo "Command gave a non-zero return code"`

The `&&` means "Only run if the previous command was successful."

Try running the ffmpeg command without the re-direct and see if you get an error. Also, check the return code immediately after execution:
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4;echo $?`
`$?` is the return code. (You have to echo, or capture it immediately after the command, otherwise it will change to the return code of the next command).

I will bet that the return code is not zero.

If your goal is to run the copy command regardless of the success or failure of ffmpeg, replace the `&&` with semi-colon `;`
`fmpeg -i video.mp4 2>d.txt ; cp ../file1.txt file1.txt`

This is exactly the same as:
`fmpeg -i video.mp4 2>d.txt`
`cp ../file1.txt file1.txt`
Just on one line.
To capture the return code of ffmpeg for later, do this:
`fmpeg -i video.mp4 2>d.txt;rc=$?;cp ../file1.txt file1.txt`
`...`
`if [ $rc -ne 0 ] ...`

If you want to copy to execute only if the ffmpeg command fails, change the `&&` to `||` like this:
`fmpeg -i video.mp4 2>d.txt || cp ../file1.txt file1.txt`

Comment: Thanks that ";" method worked perfectly! I have accepted your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: shouldn't the last line have `&&` instead of `%%`?

Comment: Yes. #NerdHands don't always type what the mind says.